# Does a symmetric matrix with only three types of values have always three types of eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, hessian-matrix

The title is quite explicit, however I will give the context. I'm referring to spin-glass theory in classical statistical mechanics, in particular to the Sherrington-Kirkpatrick model. Studying the stability of the Replica Symmetric (RS) solution one must compute the eigenvalues of an Hessian matrix which looks like the following matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
P & Q & Q & Q & Q & R \\
Q & P & Q & Q & R & Q \\
Q & Q & P & R & Q & Q \\
Q & Q & R & P & Q & Q \\
Q & R & Q & Q & P & Q \\
R & Q & Q & Q & Q & P 
\end{pmatrix}$$
but the size is not fixed and can increase, thus the structure of the matrix becomes much more complicated and cannot simply written with a general expression. What happen is that the sum of the rows (or columns) is always the same value, which implies that an eigenvector is the one with all equal elements and the corresponding eigenvalue is the sum of the row. Other reasonings can be done to compute the other two distinct eigenvalues (for instance another eigenvector is given by something like $v_a+v_b$ where $\sum_{a}v_a$=0, but I don't understand why).

What I ask here is that if there is a way to prove that a symmetric matrix with only three distinct elements has always only three distinct eigenvalues. Possibly I would like to have a way to compute directly the eigenvectors and eigenvalues without diagonalize the matrix (which is an impossible task for a general size of the matrix, as I need).

Comment: There are a [variety of algorithms for calculating eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm). Your case might be reducible to a sparse matrix, or at least have algorithms similar to sparse matrices, since for large dimensions almost all of entries are $Q$

Comment: I'm sorry, my question was not clear. I showed the specific case of the $6x6$ matrix but the structure is not the same for every size, for example the $4x4$ case is different, it has no the antidiagonal with the same values, if you are referring to something like 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
P & Q & Q & R  \\
Q & P & R & Q  \\
Q & R & P & Q  \\
R & Q & Q & P  
\end{pmatrix}$$.

However I found that the following matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
P & P & Q & R  \\
P & R & R & Q  \\
Q & R & P & Q  \\
R &  Q & Q & P  
\end{pmatrix}$$

has four different eigenvalues, so my claim is not always true.

Comment: Alas, my mind-reading skills have always been low, so I can only work with the information given, but your final paragraph is about any symmetric matrix with only three element values, and the $4\times 4$ matrix I used still fits that description, so the answer is still no. The second comment is also still relevant.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your second comment too. 

By the way, concerning your first comment, I tried to compute the eigenvalues for the $4x4$ matrix with the "antidiagonal" element R to check your claim, but I found only three distinct eigenvalues: 

$$P - R$$
$$P - 2 Q + R$$
$$P + 2 Q + R$$

where the first is twice degenerate. The second $4x4$ matrix I found has, however, four distinct eigenvalues, so you are right: not all symmetric matrices with only three distinct elements have only three distinct eigenvalues

Comment: I applied a trick for calculating $n\times n$ determinants that I often use for $n=3$, but I overlooked that the signs work differently when $n$ is even. Thus my original calculation has some sign errors. I've removed the mistaken comment, as well as the one that doesn't fully apply.